# Adding datetime field to recarray — revisited

Tags: numpy

I have a `recarray` obtained using `np.recfromcsv`, one of its fields
being an array of strings

```
In [220]: data['data']
Out[220]:
array(['2019-12-31', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', ..., '2020-03-01',
       '2020-03-02', '2020-03-10'], dtype='<U10')
```

I want to plot some of the other fields against the dates and, as far
as I know, I have to convert the date strings to `datetime` objects

```
In [221]: dt = np.array([dateutil.parser.parse(d) for d in data['date']])
     ...: dt
Out[221]:
array([datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 31, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 2, 0, 0), ...,
       datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 10, 0, 0)], dtype=object)
```

Because it's handy to filter on some field value before plotting

```
In [222]: filtered = data[data['comune']=='Busto Arsizio']
```

I'd like to add the `dt` array to `data` as a new field, but…

```
In [223]: np.lib.recfunctions.append_fields(data, 'dt', dt)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-224-b048aaed3e78> in <module>
----> 1 np.lib.recfunctions.append_fields(data, 'dt', dt)

<__array_function__ internals> in append_fields(*args, **kwargs)

~/lib/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/recfunctions.py in append_fields(base, names, data, dtypes, fill_value, usemask, asrecarray)
    716     if dtypes is None:
    717         data = [np.array(a, copy=False, subok=True) for a in data]
--> 718         data = [a.view([(name, a.dtype)]) for (name, a) in zip(names, data)]
    719     else:
    720         if not isinstance(dtypes, (tuple, list)):

~/lib/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/recfunctions.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    716     if dtypes is None:
    717         data = [np.array(a, copy=False, subok=True) for a in data]
--> 718         data = [a.view([(name, a.dtype)]) for (name, a) in zip(names, data)]
    719     else:
    720         if not isinstance(dtypes, (tuple, list)):

~/lib/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_internal.py in _view_is_safe(oldtype, newtype)
    459
    460     if newtype.hasobject or oldtype.hasobject:
--> 461         raise TypeError("Cannot change data-type for object array.")
    462     return
    463

TypeError: Cannot change data-type for object array.
```

---

What I'm missing?

---

I know that [this
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739733/adding-datetime-field-to-recarray)
has the same title but it deals, afaict, with a different
backtrace/problem.

Comment: Clearly the `dt` is object dtype array.  For one reason or other this `append_fields` function can handle that.  `recfunctions` is not an actively developed or robust subpackage (except for some recent additions to handle multiple-field indexing).  The do-it-yourself append in my old answer is still your best alternative.

Comment: can't handle that :)

Comment: @hpaulj OK for the do-it-yourself append in your old answer.  I'll comment further under it.